# How to show parent-child multi-dimensional array in a <select> dropdown menu in PHP?

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I have some record in the DB like this:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|  id  |   title_en   |         uid         |   parent_id  |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|   1  |    Food      |   ehek330pdldie827  |      0       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|   2  |   Cuisines   |  8393kdo02o923awi20 |      0       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|   3  |  Fast Food   |  ri29jnwu29823urns0 |      1       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|   4  |   British    | eo301ks8292ke9202ms |      2       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|   5  |   Chinese    |  yh39kj201203msik7e |      2       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|   6  |   Outdoor    |  hsuw8920slsl7729kj |      0       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

I am fetching the data in array format and then creating a multi-dimensional array for parent-child relation.

```
public function build_tree(array $array, $parent_id = 0, $visibility_for = Globals::COLLAPSIBLE_TREE) 
{
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($array as $element)
    {
        // iterate through each item of the list
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parent_id) 
        {
            // if parent id matches, proceed to fetch the child
            $children = $this->build_tree($array, $element['id']);  // fetch the child
            if ($children)
            {
                // if child is not empty, proceed to feed the child in separate node
                if($visibility_for == Globals::COLLAPSIBLE_TREE)
                {   
                    // if "visibility for" value is collapsible tree, keep the node as "nodes"
                    $element['nodes'] = $children;
                }
                else
                {
                    // if "visibility for" value is not collapsible tree, keep the node as "children"
                    $element['children'] = $children;
                }
            }
            $branch[] = $element;   // feed the total record in the new array
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

The record is in array format like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [text] => Food
            [href] => #Food
            [parent_id] => 0
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [text] => Fast Food
                            [href] => #Fast Food
                            [parent_id] => 1
                        )
                )
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [text] => Cuisines
            [href] => #Cuisines
            [parent_id] => 0
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [text] => Brtish
                            [href] => #Brtish
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        ),

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [text] => Chinese
                            [href] => #Chinese
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )
                )
        ) 
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [text] => Outdoor
            [href] => #Outdoor
            [parent_id] => 0
            [nodes] => Array
                (

                )
        )
)
```

My concern is how to put display these records as **options** in a `<select>` dropdown menu? The child categories need to have some '--' in front of the title. Watch the following example:

```
Food
-- Fast Food
Cuisines
-- British
-- Chinese
Outdoor
```

How can I achieve this?

JSON format for the multidimesional array

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "tree": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "text": "Food",
      "href": "#Food",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "text": "Fast Food",
          "href": "#Fast Food",
          "parent_id": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "text": "Cuisines",
      "href": "#Cuisines",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "text": "British",
          "href": "#British",
          "parent_id": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "text": "Chinese",
          "href": "#Chinese",
          "parent_id": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "text": "Outdoor",
      "href": "#Outdoor",
      "parent_id": "0",
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share a JSON encoded version of your structured data? It would help with testing.

Comment: @GiamPy updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Optgroups.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Example:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Food">
    <option value="Fast Food">-- Fast Food</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Cuisines">
    <option value="British">-- British</option>
    <option value="Chinese">-- Chinese</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Fast food & Cuisines should also be options, not optgroups